# spss custom tables crashing when row matches column

Tags: spss

I've defined a function for running batches of custom tables:

```
DEFINE !xtables (myvars=!CMDEND) 

CTABLES  
 /VLABELS VARIABLES=!myvars retailer total DISPLAY=LABEL   
/TABLE !myvars [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0, TOTALS[UCOUNT F40.0]] BY retailer [c] + total [c]   
/SLABELS POSITION=ROW   
/CRITERIA CILEVEL=95   
/CATEGORIES VARIABLES=!myvars ORDER=D KEY=COLPCT.COUNT (!myvars) EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES LABEL='Base' POSITION=AFTER   
/COMPARETEST TYPE=PROP ALPHA=.05 ADJUST=BONFERRONI ORIGIN=COLUMN INCLUDEMRSETS=YES CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE MERGE=YES STYLE=SIMPLE SHOWSIG=NO 
!ENDDEFINE.

I can then run a series for commands to run these in one batch.

!XTABLES MYVARS=q1.

!XTABLES MYVARS=q2.

!XTABLES MYVARS=q3.
```

However, if a table has the same row and column, Custom Tables freezes:

!XTABLES MYVARS=retailer.

The culprit appears to be SLABELS. I hadn't encountered this problem before v24.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating a `CTABLES` spec as close as possible to yours and found that `VLABELS`does not like the same variable specified twice.

```
GET FILE="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".
CTABLES /VLABELS VARIABLES=Gender Gender DISPLAY=LABEL
/TABLE  Gender[c][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0, TOTALS[UCOUNT F40.0]]
   BY Gender[c] /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
/CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Gender ORDER=D KEY=COLPCT.COUNT(Gender) .
```

Which yields an error message:

```
VLABELS: Text GENDER. The same keyword, option, or subcommand is used more than once.
```

Comment: So I removed the second reference to the variable from the Variables command. When run against another variable, it seems to work. When run against itself, it still crashes.

Comment: Crashes? Please describe? If there is an error message, please provide details.

Comment: No error message. The processor simply gets stuck "Running CTables..." as indicated in the status bar.

Comment: Do you have a large dataset? Try generating a sample dataset from it, say 5% of random records, for example. And test if problem still persist

Comment: Not sure why problem persists, but workaround was to create temporary clones that I only use for defining columns in the table, and then deleting once tables are run. Perhaps not the most efficient approach, but met the need. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

The macro has a parmeter named MYVARS, which suggests that more than one variable can be listed, however, if you do that, it will generate an invalid command.  Something else to watch out for.  I can see the infinite loop in V24.  In V23, an error message is produced.